# Is it possible to invoke AWS CloudFormation dynamically from Lambda to create resources on adhoc basis?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I want to provision some **AWS resources like API Gateway, Lambda, and creation of a table in the DynamoDB using the Cloud Formation template**. Now the catch is I can write a Cloud Formation template to create these resources manually or using the CI/CD server to trigger the commands like `sam build` or `sam deploy` or `aws create-stack` commands. But my requirement is to invoke this CloudFormation template (to create these new resources on demand) whenever a request comes in from a user.

There are already existing API Gateway (old), Lambda (old), and whenever an end-user will be submitting a request it will go through with these resources but I'm not sure if I can use this old Lambda to trigger the Cloud Formation template to create AWS resources dynamically and sends back **the endpoint of new created API Gateway** so that end-user can use that new endpoint to fetches data from newly created Dynamodb table.

Any reference pointer or suggestions will be really great. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I don't see a reason why you wouldn't be able to trigger deployment of your CloudFromation (CFN) template from lambda.  But the issue is that CFN templates take time, and API gateway will only wait 30s for response from your lambda function.  Its unlikely your CFN template would be able to deploy in such a short time, but you can measure deployment time to check it.

Comment: Thanks for raising the concern. I can tweak my current system's architecture and make user's request to be pushed to a SQS queue here first and send a happy response back to them. And later run a Lambda that would read the message from SQS queue and provision the new resources using the Cloud Formation template. Once done, then send an email to end user with the new API Gateway endpoint. However, the main question comes back is how to trigger CF template from Lambda or SQS queue message event. I would really appreciate if you can share some reference links to achieve this. Thank you

Comment: No problem. With CFN, you want to use cloudformation tools, or you are aiming at running `sam build` or `sam deploy` in lambda? Or `create_stack` from cloudforamtion is enough?

Comment: Since, I'm aiming to create all serverless resources here like a new API Gateway endpoint, a new Lambda (for business logic to read from DynamoDB table) and a new Dynamodb table so I will stick with sam build or sam deploy commands.